# Insert a row into an array in R

Tags: r

I have an array of dim `c(10, 12, 20,  14, 5)` and I want to insert an empty row, so at the end dim should be `c(10, 13, 20,  14, 5)`. Is there any quickly and elegant way to do that (avoiding loops)?

Comment: (Please go back and accept something from [your questions that have numerous answers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7232584/wencheng-lau-medrano).)

Comment: You aren't _required_ to accept answers, but it is considered polite, if one of the answers solved your problem. It's very useful for people landing on the question in the future to signal to them which answer actually worked for you. It's a very simple & easy way for you to give back a little in exchange for having received help.

Comment: I don't understand very well your suggestions. Are they related with the redaction? Was I rude? English is not my first language, so do you think that I used some non-polite words?

Comment: You will see check marks next to each answer. Have you noticed other questions on this site where one of the answers has a green check mark next to it? That is what we are referring to. It is considered polite to click on the check mark next to the answer that solved your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think package [`abind`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/abind/index.html) can help. The trick is creating an array with the same dimensions but replacing the augmenting dim with just 1:

```
# original array
a <- array(seq.int(2*3*4), dim=c(2, 3, 4))
# slice to be added to the second axis
b <- array(100+seq.int(2*1*4), dim=c(2, 1, 4))

library(abind)
d <- abind(a, b, along=2)
dim(d)
# [1] 2 4 4
d
# , , 1
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]    1    3    5  101
# [2,]    2    4    6  102
# , , 2
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]    7    9   11  103
# [2,]    8   10   12  104
# , , 3
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]   13   15   17  105
# [2,]   14   16   18  106
# , , 4
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]   19   21   23  107
# [2,]   20   22   24  108
```

Comment: Thank you, so I guess that I would need to make a loop to insert rows in different positions, right?

Comment: If you are adding content to different axes, yes. If you are appending multiple slices to the same dimension, you can just change to `dim=c(2,n,4)` (using this example) where `n` is the number of slices to add.